# How to customize / manage the salesforce communities in production

Tags: community

I have created the communities in production by manual, is in preview state. I want to edit this communities but i am not able to find the link 'Manage' to manage/ edit the communities.

Please advise me how can i edit my community

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

you might find administration setting in community section or something similar to that. As far as my knowledge in community dealing it need some Manage community permission under the profile of that particular User. please do verify that also. in case of help do ask.
hope this helped u bit